# LVM on SSD has very high write latency

Tags: lvm, raid, ssd

I'm  benchmarking   lvm raid10 on ssd and postgresql 13.

`vgcreate tst3vg /dev/mapper/3600140500000[123456789a]00006a0000000000000`

`lvcreate --type raid10 -i 5 -m 1 -L 8850G -n lv_tst --raidintegrity y  --raidintegritymode bitmap --raidintegrityblocksize 4096 tst3vg /dev/mapper/3600140500000[123456789a]00006a0000000000000`

`mkfs.xfs /dev/tst3vg/lv_tst`
`mount -o noatime,nodiratime /dev/tst3vg/lv_tst /tst3`
initdb ...
`pgbench -h 127.0.0.1 -p 15534 -i -s 1000 bench`
`pgbench -h 127.0.0.1 -p 15534 -c 300 -j 150 -T 172800 -s 1000 bench`

`dmsetup ls | grep tst3vg`

```
...
tst3vg-lv_tst   (254:477)
...
```

`iostat -xm dm-477 /dev/mapper/3600140500000[123456789a]00006a0000000000000 5`

...

```
Device      r/s     rMB/s   r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   w_await wareq-sz    aqu-sz  %util
dm-102   790.80     29.90      0.32    38.72 3091.20     81.96      1.00    27.15      3.35  76.08
dm-126   812.00     29.91      0.34    37.72 3127.20     82.19      0.93    26.91      3.20  75.84
dm-158   814.40     29.91      0.34    37.61 3115.60     81.92      0.90    26.92      3.07  76.08
dm-17    798.00     29.91      0.53    38.38 3936.40    112.09      0.97    29.16      4.23  76.00
dm-203     0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00      0.00   0.00
dm-251   805.40     29.90      0.32    38.02 3090.00     81.95      0.81    27.16      2.76  76.08
dm-282   815.00     29.91      0.33    37.58 3105.40     81.90      0.88    27.01      3.01  76.00
dm-309   782.60     29.91      0.35    39.14 3141.60     82.14      0.83    26.77      2.88  75.60
dm-358   776.80     29.90      0.56    39.42 3894.20    112.03      0.89    29.46      3.89  75.60
dm-415   807.80     29.91      0.35    37.92 3127.60     82.19      0.77    26.91      2.68  75.68
**dm-477     0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00 17799.00    397.26     36.20    22.85    644.28  58.24**
dm-50    781.40     29.90      0.36    39.18 3124.60     82.11      1.10    26.91      3.72  74.96

Device       r/s     rMB/s   r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wMB/s   w_await wareq-sz    aqu-sz  %util
dm-102   1128.80     40.76      0.34    36.98 3340.20     72.52      0.78    22.23       2.97  92.40
dm-126   1152.60     40.77      0.33    36.23 3324.00     72.63      0.75    22.37       2.87  92.08
dm-158   1149.00     40.77      0.34    36.34 3346.60     72.41      0.71    22.16       2.75  92.56
dm-17    1130.80     40.77      0.50    36.92 4434.20    113.51      0.82    26.21       4.21  92.88
dm-203      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00    0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00       0.00   0.00
dm-251   1144.20     40.76      0.35    36.48 3341.20     72.52      0.60    22.23       2.41  92.32
dm-282   1155.20     40.77      0.34    36.14 3346.60     72.41      0.69    22.16       2.70  92.32
dm-309   1117.80     40.77      0.39    37.35 3304.80     72.70      0.63    22.53       2.53  92.16
dm-358   1112.00     40.77      0.48    37.55 4448.00    113.34      0.67    26.09       3.51  92.32
dm-415   1145.60     40.77      0.34    36.45 3322.80     72.63      0.58    22.38       2.32  91.92
**dm-477      0.00      0.00      0.00     0.00 8317.80    162.57   4468.04    20.01    37164.29  58.64**
dm-50    1115.80     40.77      0.37    37.42 3338.80     72.55      0.90    22.25       3.41  92.16
```

...

The device dm-447 is lv_tst .
Usually,the LVM's write latency is 20-40 milliseconds. I find that sometimes LVM's write waiting is very high, the relative disk's write latency is very low.

Comment: do you have a question?  this site is for questions and answers, not for posting random factoids.

Comment: I expect the implicit question is, why is it high and how do I make LVM not have unacceptably high latency.